# Jest.js how to test if a method that returns JSX has rendered if a condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsx

I am new to Jest. Not sure if I should check for the modal or if method is rendered. How would I do so?
I have the following class component:

```
export class HelloWorld extends Component<Props> {
    renderModal(name: string, email: string) {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <div>
                     <p>Hello World</p>
                </div>
            </ Modal>
        )
    }

    render() {
      const { auth: { isUserVerified, name, email }}
        <div>
            {isUserVerified || this.renderModal(name, email)}
        </div>
    }
}
```

And in Jest

```
describe('renderModal', () => {
    test.('it renders renderModal if isUserVerified is false', () => {
        const props = {
            ...propsFixture
            isUserVerified: false;
        }
        const component = shallow(<HellowWorld {...props} />);
        expect(component.contains(<Modal />)).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

Comment: Doesn't it render the modal if `isUserVerified` is *false*?

Comment: You got it, my mistake. Yup it renders is it is false. I updated it.

Comment: Did you forget to deconstruct the `auth` from `this.props`?